# placing child element of xml in variable

Tags: python-3.x, xml

Hi I'm new to xml never used it before and I'm trying to place two child elements in a variable each. So here's the XML data I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
<counties>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
  </country>
</countries>
<cities>
        <city id="1036323110">
        <city>Katherine</city>
        <country>Australia</country>
        <capital>Australia</capital>
        <population>1488</population>
  </city>
</cities>
</data>
```

So I'm trying to get a variable that contains each child branch and this is what I've tried so far:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
country = root.find(".//countries")
city = root.find(".//cities")
```

Am I right in approaching it in this method? Thank you

Comment: and the issue you're facing is ...?

Comment: I'd like to know if what I'm doing is right because I'd like to use the variables as input for my pandas data frame @Tomalak